# Touchpad doesn't wake up from suspend

Tags: arch-linux, suspend, touchpad

I've been trying to figure out how I can make my touchpad work after waking up from suspend.

Until recently I could at least reactivate it by typing:

```
ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/mouse
sudo modprobe -v synaptics_i2c
```

(btw how can I actually determine which driver is handling my touchpad? `lspci -k` isn't helping me and I'm fairly new to linux?)

A recent kernel update caused this method to not work anymore.  I've found this solution, but it doesn't work

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad
sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad
```

and paste in the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    suspend|hibernate)
         modprobe -r psmouse ;;
    resume|thaw)
        modprobe psmouse ;;
esac
```

Finally, making it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad
```

How can I get my touchpad to work after waking from suspend?

Comment: Hi and welcome to unix.SE.  A better way to format your question as code is to indent code blocks by four spaces.  See the edits I've made to your question.

Comment: Your question about determining which driver is handling your touchpad should be asked as a separate question.  That way it's more which answers are for which questions (and people have an easier time finding that answer when searching in the future).

Comment: Are you sure the first line in your old method is correct? `ls /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/kernel/drivers/input/mouse` will only print out that file path (expanding `uname -r`).  It doesn't change anything in the system...

Answer (score 3):

I would simply try disabling/enabling it via `xinput` instead. You can do this by acquiring the devices `id=#` from the `xinput` command.

```
$ xinput --list | grep TouchPad
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

You can parse the `id=` using this command:

```
$ TID=$(xinput list | grep -iPo 'touchpad.*id=\K\d+')
```

And then disable/enable it:

```
$ xinput disable "$TID"
$ xinput enable "$TID"
```

Comment: I have this problem and my touchpad is not listed when I type `$ xinput`.  There is only the XTEST virtual pointer and my ELAN touchscreen.

Comment: Ask a new Q on the site. Reference this Q&A saying that it doesn't work for your particular situation, see if someone can help.