# TouchPad not working on Chromebook

Tags: linux, linux-mint, touchpad

I have just done a complete install of Linux Mint on a Toshiba Chromebook. All is working except I can't get the touchpad to move the pointer at all. I have to move around trying to do everything with the keyboard. Is there anything I can do to make it so the touchpad is recognized? When I run `xinput --list` it shows the keyboard but not a touchpad.

Comment: This might help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197457

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) the model of your laptop; ii) if you know them, the hardware details of your touchpad; iii) the output of `xinput --list`; iv) tell us if it works on another operating system or if you boot into a live CD; v) tell us if you've checked if there's a button that activates/deactivates your touchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the touchpad is not showing up in `xinput`, its driver has certainly failed to load. You should check `dmesg` output after a reboot, chances are you will see the driver complaining about missing firmware files or bad configuration. Also, many touchpads are presented as USB devices, so try to identify yours with `lsusb`. I assume the touchpad worked in ChromeOS, otherwise it may also be a hardware issue (replugging the cables often helps in such case).

Also, as silly as it sounds, try toggling the touchpad Fn switch, or whatever those hardware bottons are called on a chromebook.

The answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131432/which-driver-is-handling-my-touchpad) should help if you have a hard time figuring out what driver is supposed to manage your touchpad.